# How do you retrieve individual DNA sequences after importing an alignment into R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I imported an alignment in FASTA format into R

```
    read.dna(file.choose(),format="fasta",skip=0)
```

My alignment looks something like this

```
Seq1 ATGCGGGAATGGACTCATGCATCG
Seq2 ATTCGATCTTGCTAGCTAGCTCGT
Seq3 ATATCGATGTCGATCGATCGACGA
```

If I want to call individual sequences from within this alignment (say Seq2 for example), what do I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `read.dna()` comes from (there are >6000 CRAN packages, and almost 1000 [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/) packages). You could use the [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package and

```
library(Biostrings)
dna = readDNAStringSet("path/to.fasta")
```

and do many useful things, including those described in the [quick reference](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Biostrings/inst/doc/BiostringsQuickOverview.pdf). If at the end you want a single character vector, then

```
as.character(dna[1])
```

or

```
as.character(dna[names(dna) == "Seq3"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using `ape` package.  Using the example in `?read.dna`

```
library(ape)
cat(">No305",
"NTTCGAAAAACACACCCACTACTAAAANTTATCAGTCACT",
">No304",
"ATTCGAAAAACACACCCACTACTAAAAATTATCAACCACT",
">No306",
"ATTCGAAAAACACACCCACTACTAAAAATTATCAATCACT",
file = "exdna.txt", sep = "\n")
ex.dna4 <- read.dna("exdna.txt", format = "fasta")

ex.dna4[dimnames(ex.dna4)[[1]]=='No304',]
#1 DNA sequences in binary format stored in a matrix.

#All sequences of same length: 40 

#Labels: No304 

#Base composition:
#    a     c     g     t 
#0.475 0.300 0.025 0.200 

as.character(ex.dna4[dimnames(ex.dna4)[[1]]=='No304'])
#[1] "a" "t" "t" "c" "g" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "c" "a" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c" "a" "c"
#[20] "t" "a" "c" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "t" "t" "a" "t" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "a"
#[39] "c" "t"
```